# $setDirty() from jQuery is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive which wraps a jQuery element, this directive is binded to an object which contains some callback functions as following:

```
vm.treeEvents = {
    check_node: function(node, selected){
        vm.form.$setDirty();
        ...
    },
    uncheck_node: function(node, selected){
        vm.form.$setDirty();
        ...
    }
};
```

In the directive post link function I have this :

```
if (scope.tree.treeEvents.hasOwnProperty(evt)) {
    scope.tree.treeView.on(evt.indexOf('.') > 0 ? evt : evt + '.jstree', scope.tree.treeEvents[evt]);
}
```

so whenever an event declared in the `treeEvents` scope binding is triggered, the callback function is executed, and then the form is set to `dirty` state.

When I did this I noticed that the form is not passed to the dirty state unless I scroll the page or I click on some element in the form.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `scope.$evalAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common `AngularJS` issue, because of the fact that you `jQuery` trigger is "outside of Angular's world" you should let `Angular` to know about it via calling to `$scope.$apply` inside the event handler.

More info, read [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) docs.